# Trouble Updating plotly in R

Tags: r, r-plotly, quantitative-finance, candlestick-chart

I am having trouble plotting candlestick charts with plotly.  Apparently, candlestick is not one of the types I can do with the version I have installed, which is 4.5.2.  So I am trying to update plotly to the latest 4.7.1 version by doing this:

```
devtools::install_github("ropensci/plotly")
```

But this is the error I got:

```
> devtools::install_github("ropensci/plotly")
Downloading GitHub repo ropensci/plotly@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/ropensci/plotly/zipball/master
Installing plotly
"C:/PROGRA~1/MICROS~3/RCLIEN~1/R_SERVER/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD  \
  INSTALL "C:/Users/cinji/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpMNgiEt/devtools27f029a57c1a/ropensci-plotly-2cc296d"  \
  --library="C:/Users/cinji/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.3" --install-tests 

ERROR: dependencies 'rlang', 'crosstalk', 'promises' are not available for package 'plotly'
* removing 'C:/Users/cinji/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/plotly'
Error: Command failed (1)
```

What's going on?  What do I need to do?

Thank you.

---

Update:  I tried one of the answers below which was this:

```
install.packages(c('rlang', 'crosstalk', 'promises'))
```

But I got this:

```
> install.packages(c('rlang', 'crosstalk', 'promises'))
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing packages into ‘C:/Users/cinji/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  packages ‘rlang’, ‘crosstalk’, ‘promises’ are not available (for R version 3.3.2)
```

Does that mean I have to install another version of R?  "About RStudio" tells me I have Version 1.2.1335 © 2009-2019 RStudio, Inc.

Comment: Perhaps you can add a paramter dependencies = True. See help in install.

Comment: Tried this.  devtools::install_github("ropensci/plotly", dependencies = TRUE)  Same error.

Comment: You should download a newer version of R, your RStudio is not the problem. They're at 3.6.0 as of today. Also, I have run into errors with specifying ```dependencies=TRUE``` in the past, and noticed that just using ```install.packages()``` works better.

Comment: Ok. That's so weird because I just updated R a couple weeks ago.  Thanks.

Comment: It looks like your RStudio is recognizing that you’re using R version 3.3.2. I noticed that on windows, downloading a new version of R will not delete an older version. Although I never ran into this problem, but your RStudio could have not recognize your new install. I recommend that you delete your older versions of R. Note that deleting older versions of R will delete all your packages but using a new version of R will require you to download the packages again anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I don't enough reputation at the moment to comment, so I'll put this as an answer.
You need to install the dependencies first.

```
install.packages(c('rlang', 'crosstalk', 'promises'))
```